# Using ExecuteNonQuery or ExecuteReader for both return objects and Output parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a web service. One function uses a stored procedure which return output parameters and a class object(for XML).

This is my web service (VB.net):

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Function Search(ByVal ID As String,ByRef ROW As String) As List(Of Entity)


        Dim log As String = ""
        Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim ListOfEntity As List(Of Entity) = New List(Of Entity)
        Try
            sqlconn.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconn
            sqlconn.Open()

            sqlcmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sqlcmd.CommandText = "ENTITY_DETAILS"
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)

            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ROW", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            sqlcmd.Parameters("@ROW").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

            Dim result = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim ROWValue = sqlcmd.Parameters("@ROW").Value

            Dim sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
            If sqlreader IsNot Nothing And sqlreader.HasRows Then
                While sqlreader.Read()
                    ListOfEntity.Add(New Entity With
                    {
```

Should I use the following statement to explicitly bind the output parameter

```
Dim ROWValue = sqlcmd.Parameters("@ROW").Value
```

Or do I need to bind this way

```
ROW = sqlcmd.Parameters("@ROW").Value
```

Or it will get bind implicitly.

Kindly clarify if both `ExecuteScalar` and `ExecuteReader` have to be used for the two results.

Tthe requirement is: the web service will take some parameters and return an output parameter with some class objects as an XML.

Comment: *"Should I use the following statement to explicitly bind the output parameter or it will be done implicitly"*. Why do you need to ask us something that you can find out for yourself with a simple test?

Comment: *"Kindly clarify if both ExecuteScalar and ExecuteReader has to be used for the two results"*. If you understand what `ExecuteScalar` does then the answer to that is obvious.

Comment: Your question doesn't include the code of the stored procedure, which means we have no way of verifying whether what you've written is correct, or answering any of the question